# Way to find Facebook reach from my app posts?

Tags: facebook, social-networking

Is there a way to retrieve the reach from my App posts?

Example:
My app posts photos on a specific fan page, I would like to retrieve the reach that my app provided to that fanpage in order to show them how awesome my app is.

Answer (score 7):

Using the page access token for the page you manage, (with `read_insights` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)).

You can then access `/POST_ID/insights` to retrieve insights information about that post.

For a sample post on my page, this returns the impressions data for the post.
Excerpt:

```
{
      "id": "[ID REMOVED]/insights/post_story_adds_by_action_type/lifetime", 
      "name": "post_story_adds_by_action_type", 
      "period": "lifetime", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": {
            "like": 20, 
            "comment": 3, 
            "share": 1
          }
        }
      ], 
      "title": "Lifetime Post Stories by action type", 
      "description": "Lifetime The number of stories created about your Page post, by action type. (Total Count)"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "[ID REMOVED]/insights/post_impressions_unique/lifetime", 
      "name": "post_impressions_unique", 
      "period": "lifetime", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 936
        }
      ], 
      "title": "Lifetime Post Total Reach", 
      "description": "Lifetime The number of people who saw your Page post. (Unique Users)"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "[ID REMOVED]/insights/post_impressions/lifetime", 
      "name": "post_impressions", 
      "period": "lifetime", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 2936
        }
      ], 
      "title": "Lifetime Post Total Impressions", 
      "description": "Lifetime The number of impressions of your Page post. (Total Count)"
    },
```

The blog post from when this was launched is here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/573/
And the `insights` connection is mentioned in the [Post documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)